# Пропадают названия шрифтов из селекта при выборе шрифта с пробелом

Tags: javascript, python, extjs

Есть библиотека Ext JS (3.4.2). В редакторе есть селект с выбором шрифта. При выборе option с value с пробелом в селекте не отображается выбранное значение. Хотя сам шрифт выбирается.

Код генерации селекта со шрифтами:

```js
Ext.form.HtmlEditor = Ext.extend(Ext.form.Field, {

    enableFormat : true,

    enableFontSize : false,

    enableColors : true,

    enableAlignments : true,

    enableLists : true,

    enableSourceEdit : true,

    enableLinks : true,

    enableFont : true,

    createLinkText : 'Please enter the URL for the link:',

    defaultLinkValue : 'http:/'+'/',

    fontFamilies : [
        'Arial',
        'Courier New', //keka2
        'Tahoma',
        'Times New Roman',
        'Verdana',
    ],
    defaultFont: 'arial',

    defaultValue: (Ext.isOpera || Ext.isIE6) ? '&#160;' : '&#8203;',


    actionMode: 'wrap',
    validationEvent : false,
    deferHeight: true,
    initialized : false,
    activated : false,
    sourceEditMode : false,
    iframePad:3,
    hideMode:'offsets',
    defaultAutoCreate : {
        tag: "textarea",
        style:"width:500px;height:300px;",
        autocomplete: "off"
    },


    initComponent : function(){
        this.addEvents(

            'initialize',

            'activate',

            'beforesync',

            'beforepush',

            'sync',

            'push',

            'editmodechange'
        );
        Ext.form.HtmlEditor.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },


    createFontOptions : function(){
        var buf = [], fs = this.fontFamilies, ff, lc;
        for(var i = 0, len = fs.length; i< len; i++){
            ff = fs[i]; //keka1
            lc = ff.toLowerCase();
            buf.push(
                '<option value="',lc,'" label="',ff,'" style="font-family:',ff,';"',
                    (!this.defaultFont == lc ? ' selected="true">' : '>'),
                    ff,
                '</option>'
            );
        }
        return buf.join('');
    },


    createToolbar : function(editor){
        var items = [];
        var tipsEnabled = Ext.QuickTips && Ext.QuickTips.isEnabled();


        function btn(id, toggle, handler){
            return {
                itemId : id,
                cls : 'x-btn-icon',
                iconCls: 'x-edit-'+id,
                enableToggle:toggle !== false,
                scope: editor,
                handler:handler||editor.relayBtnCmd,
                clickEvent:'mousedown',
                tooltip: tipsEnabled ? editor.buttonTips[id] || undefined : undefined,
                overflowText: editor.buttonTips[id].title || undefined,
                tabIndex:-1
            };
        }


        if(this.enableFont && !Ext.isSafari2){
            var fontSelectItem = new Ext.Toolbar.Item({
               autoEl: {
                    tag:'select',
                    cls:'x-font-select',
                    html: this.createFontOptions()
               }
            });

            items.push(
                fontSelectItem,
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подебажал код HtmlEditor, как оказалось баг с выбором шрифта возникает в этом участке кода - updateToolbar. Если закоментировать проверку "name != this.fontSelect.dom.value", то шрифты в селекте не пропадают, при этом тексту продолжает присваиваться нужный выбранный шрифт. Происходит это из-за того, значение value (если посмотреть this.fontSelect) постоянно пустое. Но вот, если посмотреть напрямую сам оригинальный select, созданный в дереве dom - то выясниться что value в нем undefined постоянно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]